# Bugzilla: running checksetup.pl throwing missing module error which is already installed

Tags: ubuntu, bugzilla

I tried installing Bugzilla on my local box. Following the same setup instruction I have , I was able to setup on my other server but this time its throwing error:

When I run checksetup.pl , its showing::

COMMANDS TO INSTALL REQUIRED MODULES (You *must* run all these commands
and then re-run checksetup.pl):

```
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBI
```

To attempt an automatic install of every required and optional module
with one command, do:

/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl --all

*** Installation aborted. Read the messages above. ***

This above module is already there , but I tried again installing this using above command this says::

root@Inblrlt-jay:/var/www/bugzilla-4.4.1# /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBI
Checking for                 CPAN (v1.81)     ok: found v1.960001 
Checking for                 YAML (any)       ok: found v0.88 
Checking for   ExtUtils-MakeMaker (v6.31)     ok: found v6.84 
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 16 Dec 2013 14:07:59 GMT
Installing DBI version 1.630...
DBI is up to date (1.630).

Am I missing somewhere?

I am using Ubuntu12.0

Comment: I fixed that problem .. since this is a bug in script only so, u need to open the script and remove the condition where its checking DBI module. I was successfully able to configure Bugzilla.